# What is ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR for?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm learning Annotations and Annotation Processors.

I encountered with [javax.validation.constraints.NotNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) with its declaration of

```java
@Target(value={METHOD,FIELD,ANNOTATION_TYPE,CONSTRUCTOR,PARAMETER})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
public @interface NotNull
```

I'm already a little familiar with this annotation.

```java
@NotNull
public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

@NotNull
private String name;

private int age;
```

What kind of usages for this `@NotNull` with `ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR` states that the annotation can be classified on constructor level (when specified `@Target` on the annotation declaration).

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Request")
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    public Request() {

    }
}
```

---

The [Beans Validation Specification (1.0 final)](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/bean_validation-1_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1367913324_1261d3298ca5f456af129b1c7ac8f537) states the following (in chapter **2.1 Constraint annotation**):

> Constraint annotations can target any of the following `ElementType`s:
>
> - `FIELD` for constrained attributes
> - `METHOD` for constrained getters
> - `TYPE` for constrained beans
> - `ANNOTATION_TYPE` for constraints composing other constraints.
>
> While other `ElementType`s are not forbidden, the provider does not
>   have to recognize and process constraints placed on such types.
>   Built-in types do support `PARAMETER` and `CONSTRUCTOR` to allow Bean
>   Validation provider specific extensions. It is considered good
>   practice to follow the same approach for custom annotations.

In essence, though there hasn't been a *constructive/useful* example for using `@NotNull` on constructor level, the specification declares that it's good practice to include the `ElementType` on annotations (as the built-in annotations contains them already).

I hope this helps.

Comment: OP seems to know it can be applied to the constructor, the question is what is it used for when applied to the constructor.

Comment: So basically, there's no upside to using `@NotNull` on constructor level? There's nothing that will be validated by it? Probably just due to compatibility?

Comment: It depends on the Bean Validation provider. Remember that Bean Validation is an API, so the provider *may* decide to validate constraints on constructor level. It doesn't have to recognize it at constructor level at all.